# How to fitWidth for an image in flutter while only showing the bottom of the image?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to fit the image width into the screen as shown on the red box in the photo. However, when I use fitWidth, it crops out both the top and bottom of the image. How can I make it such that it only crops out the top and shows more of the bottom of the image?

Current code is as shown

```
Image.asset(
  'assets/images/xx.png',
   fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
 )
```

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: are you using `networkImage` or `assetImage`?

Comment: I am using image.asset.

Comment: I've added a short code snippet above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,`

```dart
 SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 400,
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/p7_image_asset.jpeg',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
```

[image]